# GUI applications in anacron

Tags: linux, cron, gui

I'm trying to run a bunch of scripts/commands every day.

For this purpose I've configured a user-space anacron as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/a/172994). Anacron is started hourly by cron:

contents of `/var/spool/cron/rawing`:

```
@hourly /usr/sbin/anacron -s -t ${HOME}/.anacron/etc/anacrontab -S ${HOME}/.anacron/spool
```

This works fine. However, I haven't managed to run any graphical applications from my anacrontab.
I've tried:

```
@daily 0 gui_test_env      env SCREEN=:0 zenity --info
@daily 0 gui_test_screen   SCREEN=:0 zenity --info
```

Both of these fail with the error message

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(zenity:6034): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Also

```
@daily 0 notify_test    SCREEN=:0.0 && notify-send "foobar"
```

didn't produce an error message, but didn't display a notification either. On the other hand, a python script that displays desktop notifications failed with the message

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rawing/Desktop/folder/python/misc/confirm_run.py", line 36, in <module>
    n.show()
GLib.Error: g-spawn-exit-error-quark: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=db6d4465f8584b8faa8abfb09b242b95 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1 (1)
```

In case it matters, the python code looks like this (shortened):

```
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init('test')
n= Notify.Notification.new('title', 'question', "dialog-question")
n.set_urgency(Notify.Urgency.NORMAL)
n.show()
```

Adding `xhost local:rawing > /dev/null` to my `~/.bashrc` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/85623) didn't help either.

---

**Update:** I've managed to run GUI applications using `DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/rawing/.Xauthority some_gui_app`. Desktop notifications still don't work though. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rawing/Desktop/folder/python/misc/confirm_run.py", line 36, in <module>
    n.show()
GLib.Error: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files (2)
```

---

P.S.: Suggestions on how to make this work *without* anacron are also welcome. I thought anacron would make this easy... turns out I was too optimistic.

Comment: `org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files` I have seen reports of similar error messages (for example, [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=75078]) on Arch and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268145/how-can-i-get-guake-to-start#comment337865_269178) on Ubuntu) for which the problem was resolved by installing a notification-daemon.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @John1024: Installing `notification-daemon` reverted the error to `GLib.Error: g-spawn-exit-error-quark: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=2a4dc02c073e450399e9f344111fbbbb --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1 (1)`.

Comment: That error message seems to be associated with a number of software bugs.  If you are on a Mac, you might need this [software update](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/39145).  On Fedora, you might need to upgrade to get [this bug fix](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=912188).  Whatever distribution that you are on, you might just want to upgrade to the most recent version.

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to run a python script from systemd timers.  `(GLib.Error: g-spawn-exit-error-quark: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=`</snip> -- did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 1):

In dealing with cron on a NAS, I've learned that executing commands directly is often counterproductive.  The solution to this is to craft a script that does everything internally.  Then have the cron task call the script that works perfectly.  This requires a couple special actions.

- Craft the script (this may be as simple as the extra line `#!bin/bash` as the first line
- Use absolute paths for EVERYTHING (often a cron environment has no paths in the environment, if it has an environment at all)

[edit] I understand that this skips a lot of the detail provided in the question post.  That is somewhat intentional.

With a bit of trial and error, here's what I got to work.

```
mkdir -p /home/username/bin/cron
nano -w /home/username/bin/cron/testscreen.sh
```

(in nano, insert the following)

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/env SCREEN=:0 DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority /usr/bin/zenity --info
```

Save the script.

```
chmod +x /home/username/bin/cron/testscreen.sh
crontab -e
```

Add the following line, adjusting the timing to your particular need.

```
20   8  *   *   *     /home/username/bin/cron/testscreen.sh
```

Mostly, I just had to look back and forth from the environment of my xterm to the environment in cron and figure out what key pieces were missing.  Took some quick footwork to get cron events to trigger "a minute from now" for testing, but I got it to work, so it should work for you.

Comment: You're saying I should put "SCREEN=:0 zenity --info" in a bash script and then make cron execute that script? If so, that didn't change anything.

Comment: @Rawing Answer revised/expanded.

Comment: Like I said before, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: If you follow the steps I laid out exactly, it doesn't work?  It took some work to get that set of steps down, but once I did, it works predictably every time.

Comment: GUI applications work regardless of whether I use a script, but desktop notifications don't work either way.

Comment: Maybe there are other variables that need to be pulled into the command.  The cron environment is VERY sparse compared to the environment that an xterm is passed.  As a cron entry, enter `*   *  *   *   *     /usr/bin/env >/home/username/cronenv.txt`  wait one minute, then comment it back out.  Then see what variables the cron is being passed.